# how to add ng-click in angular 1.4.5 using transformation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using `xslt + angular js` .I am making list of items .I am able to make it but now I want to add click event using `angular js` can I add `ng-click` here .I am using **xslt 1.0 with angular js 1.4**
here is my code

http://xsltransform.net/jxDigUu/1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="list">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <ul>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
       </ul>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"/>
        </body>

      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="name">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**data.xml**

```
<list>
    <name>A new XSLT engine is added: Saxon 9.5 EE, with a namecense (thank you Michael Kay!)</name>
    <name>XSLT 3.0 support when using the new Saxon 9.5 EE engine!</name>
    <name>Preview your result as HTML when doctype is set to HTML (see this example)</name>
    <name>Preview your result as PDF when doctype is set to XML and your document starts with root element of XSL-FO. Apache FOP is used to generate the PDF</name>
    <name>Added some namenks to useful XSLT sites</name>
</list>
```

**To check HTML**

click on `HTML` link on result window of above link

update code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="list">

   <hmtl>
            <head>
                <title>New Version!</title>
            </head>
            <body ng-app="app">
               <div ng-controller="appcontr">
                   <ul>
                       <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
                   </ul>
               </div>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"/>
                <script>
                    angular.module('app',[]).controller('appcontr',appcontr)
                    function appcontr($scope){
                    $scope.name ='dd'
                    }

                </script>
            </body>

        </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I added controller but getting error on console .
error is this

r**] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to instantiate module app due to in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725613/failed-to-instantiate-module-app-due-to-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

put the ng-app to `<html ng-app="app">` and put `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"/>` before `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

The first script needs a closing tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js">
<!-- ADD closing tag here -->
</script>

<script>
    angular.module('app',[]).controller('appcontr',appcontr)
    function appcontr($scope){
    $scope.name ='dd'
    }

</script>
```