# Failed to instantiate module app due to in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an AngularJS app .But I am getting this error:

> Failed to instantiate module app due to

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head><title>New Version!</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="appcontr">
    <ul>
        <li>A new XSLT engine is added: Saxon 9.5 EE, with a namecense (thank you Michael Kay!)</li>
        <li>XSLT 3.0 support when using the new Saxon 9.5 EE engine!</li>
        <li>Preview your result as HTML when doctype is set to HTML (see this example)</li>
        <li>Preview your result as PDF when doctype is set to XML and your document starts with root element of XSL-FO.
            Apache FOP is used to generate the PDF
        </li>
        <li>Added some namenks to useful XSLT sites</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"/>


<script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('appcontr', appcontr)
    function appcontr($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'dd'
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get any reason for failure to instantiate?

Comment: Due to **what**? Error message contains the information on what's wrong, and it was omitted from the question. It can be fixed by doing **something**.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: By failing to close the first `<script>` tag, the `angular.module` code is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, just close your script reference as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js">
</script>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('appcontr', appcontr)
    function appcontr($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'dd'
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>New Version!</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="appcontr">
<h1> {{name}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>A new XSLT engine is added: Saxon 9.5 EE, with a namecense (thank you Michael Kay!)</li>
        <li>XSLT 3.0 support when using the new Saxon 9.5 EE engine!</li>
        <li>Preview your result as HTML when doctype is set to HTML (see this example)</li>
        <li>Preview your result as PDF when doctype is set to XML and your document starts with root element of XSL-FO.
            Apache FOP is used to generate the PDF
        </li>
        <li>Added some namenks to useful XSLT sites</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please give more info  and please provide plunker

Comment: which reference ?

Comment: @user5711656 check the demo, its angular.js reference